# Finding a certain name on excel using Powershell (using loops or not)

Tags: excel, loops, powershell

I have trouble running a loop in Excel down a list in Excel (Rows), using Powershell. I am trying to scan for certain name, using $var for search in excel. Can you help me fix the problem. thanks.

```
$var="410043"

$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objExcel.Visible= $False
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\step.k\Desktop\Copy of TEST24.xlsx")
#$WorkBook.sheets | Select-Object -Property Name
$Workbook.Worksheets.Item("sheet1").Activate()

$Range = $Workbook.Range("B1: B14492").EntireRow  
$Search = $Range.find($var)  
$var
```

Comment: What if you change your `$Range` to just `$Workbook.Range("B1: B14492")`

Answer (score 1):

The following .PS1 will use [Range.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx)/[Range.FindNext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196143.aspx) methods to list all of the occurances

```
$filePath = "T:\TMP\find_410043.xlsx"
$var = "410043"
$xl = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$xl.Visible = $true
if (test-path $filePath) {
$wb = $xl.Workbooks.Open($filePath)
$ws = $wb.WorkSheets.item("sheet1")

$rc1 = $ws.Range("B1:B14492").entirerow.find($var)
if ($rc1) 
    {
    $found = 1
    $addr = $rc1.address(0, 0, 1, 0)
    do
        {
        $rc1 = $ws.cells.findnext($rc1)
        write-host $rc1.address(0, 0, 1, 0)
        } until ($addr -eq $rc1.address(0, 0, 1, 0))
    }
}
$wb.close()
$xl.quit()
```

Note that the first written to the command window is actually the second occurrence. The first is listed last and then the address matches so the loop is exited. If there is only one then there is no difference.

Comment: (I don't know powershell, so if it's specific to that, then ignore) - Why use `.entirerow.` in the `Range("B1:B14492")`? Wouldn't, if anything, `Range("B:B").EntireColumn` be better? I assume not, and am just curious why you set a range of rows, then use `entireRow` on it.

Comment: I think the OP wants to find **410043** from something like `A1:ZZ14492` as that is the current region. It's hard to say from the code provided or even what he/she wants to do with the cell once it is found.

Comment: Where'd you get `A1:ZZ__` as the current region? I just see `B1:B14492`.  I'm trying to learn powershell conventions and am just trying to understand more comprehensively.

Comment: The OP uses `$Workbook.Range("B1: B14492").EntireRow`. That actually means `A1:XFD14492` since the entire row means the entire row and not starting at column B. I can only assume that the OP has made that range determination from the data; e.g.  column B always has the maximum number of rows. (p.s. I wouldn't try to learn range determination from that; it's not 'best practise' but unless the OP is more specific is what they are trying to attempt, it is all I can offer.)

Comment: "The OP uses $Workbook.Range("B1: B14492").EntireRow. That actually means A1:XFD14492 since the entire row means the entire row and not starting at column B" Aha! I don't know why I didn't process that when I was thinking through what using `.EntireRow` would do on a range in a single column.  And yeah, that's not usually how I'd select that range...But now I see, thanks!!

Comment: Yes, I havent written codes in 6 years. Recently in my workplace. I could just automate the whole task. I forgot all the codes and forgive me if I used the code incorrectly. My computer programming skills are rusty. On cell B1:B14492 contains data for each project's name. Within the cell B1:B14492 list. I need to find "410043". I was wondering how to do it since I kept getting errors because Powershell won't process anything after $Range = $Workbook.Range("B1: B14492").EntireRow  .             PS-    $WorkSheets.Cells.Item(1,3) = “Testing" is not working..